# Why formControlName is not working in generic component?

Tags: typescript, angular-reactive-forms, typescript-generics

I am trying to make a generic component for a select dropdown. All the inputs from child works correctly on parent generic component, but for any reason the formControlName doesnt work. I have imported the ReactiveFormsModule aswell. Any idea?

Child template:

```
<app-form-input-dropdown
    [label]="'Categories'"
    [defaultValue]="'Select a category'"
    [dataList]="categories"
    [formControlName]="'category'"
  ></app-form-input-dropdown>
```

Child component ts:

```
filterMemberForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ["", [Validators.maxLength(255)]],
    role: ["", [Validators.maxLength(255)]],
    category: ["", [Validators.maxLength(255)]],
    skill: ["", [Validators.maxLength(255)]],
    skillLevels: ["", [Validators.maxLength(255)]],
    language: ["", [Validators.maxLength(255)]],
    languageLevels: ["", [Validators.maxLength(255)]],
  });
```

Generic parent template:

```
  <div class="row mb-3 form-group">
  <div class="col">
    <label class="form-label">{{ label }}</label>
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="{{formControlName}}">
      <option value="">{{ defaultValue }}</option>
      <option *ngFor="let element of dataList" [value]="element">
        {{ element }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Generic parent .ts:

```
 export class FormInputDropdownComponent {
  @Input() defaultValue: String;
  @Input() formControlName: any;
  @Input() dataList: Array<String>;
  @Input() label: String;
}
```